# Remove cookie from XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am making an ajax call with jquery like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path/to/webservice.asmx"
    beforeSend: function(xmlHTTPRequest) {
        //modify headers here
        //remove cookies
    }
    success: function() {
        //do stuff 
   }
}
```

What I would like to do in the beforeSend function is take the incoming xmlHTTPRequest variable that is set and modify the headers to remove the cookie object that is in there, so in the call to my web service, it does not renew forms authentication in asp.net

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977058/xmlhttprequest-and-set-cookie-cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Try</s>

```
xmlHTTPRequest.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "");
```

**EDIT:** It appears this does not work, at least not consistently. Read [Cookie Monster For XMLHttpRequest](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/cookie-monster-for-xmlhttprequest/)

You could also use the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to delete cookies.

```
$.cookie("nameOfCookie", null);
```

Comment: I've got another crappy error.  Now that i've removed the cookie, the ajax call is returning an error stating 12150, Unknown as the status, statustext.  I need to access the web service free of cookies so that i can not have the asp.net authentication renewed or the session renewed.

Comment: This does not remove the cookies. See http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/cookie-monster-for-xmlhttprequest/