# How to send "Cookie" in request header for all the requests in Angular2?

Tags: angular

Actually , our backend authenticate the request using Cookie in the request header. I know that it will refuse if I set a header "Cookie". So , is there a way to send a Cookie to the back end ?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I guess that there is a phase where you ask the server to authenticate you. Following this (and if the authentication is successful), the server will return a cookie in the response. The browser will store this cookie and send it again for each call.

That said, in the case of cross domain requests (CORS), you need to set the `withCredentials` of XHR to `true` to make the browser add cookies in your requests.

To enable this with Angular2, we need to extend the `BrowserXhr` class as described below:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  constructor() {}
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

and override the `BrowserXhr` provider with the extended:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CustomBrowserXhr })
]);
```

See this questions for more details:

- [Set-cookie in response not set for Angular2 post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064648/set-cookie-in-response-not-set-for-angular2-post-request/35064703#35064703)
- [xmlhttprequest and set-cookie & cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977058/xmlhttprequest-and-set-cookie-cookie)

**Edit (following the [freaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1555083/freaker)'s comment)**

From RC2, you can use the `withCredentials` property directly within the request configuration as described below:

```
this.http.get('http://...', { withCredentials: true })
```

**Edit (following the [maxou] comment)**

Remember to include withCredentials: true on **every request**.

Comment: This feature was added to angular2 now. You can now simply do something like `http.get(url, {withCredentials: true})` so this handy workaround is not needed any longer (as of 2.0.0-rc4 or earlier).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was added in RC2. I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks very much for pointing this out ;-)

Comment: it seems to me that by using `withCredentials`, the `Set-Cookie` in the response will be set by the client, but the client still does not send the `Cookie` in the request (that was set with a previous request)

Comment: Any luck with this @maxou?

Comment: coresponding angular2 docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html

Comment: I have the same problem as maxou, is there a solution for this?

Comment: @Kian use `withCredentials` in all requests

Comment: `withCredentials` will save you hours of headaches troubleshooting an issue that doesn't need to be troubleshooted. This is especially important when dealing with SAML tokens and using `client-sessions`.

Comment: agree with @occasl `withCredentials` is an absolute lifesaver.. saved a huge amount of time while working w/ JWT secured Node backend and Angular 4.4

Answer (score 39):

In Angular5 you can write a Http Interceptor:

**auth.interceptor.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true
  });
  return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

And add to providers array of app.module

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AuthInterceptor } from './services/auth.interceptor';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
imports: [
    BrowserModule,HttpClientModule,FormsModule
  ],

providers: [
    {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true,
    }
]
```

Comment: This is a great approach to reduce the clutter in all of your HTTP requests.  You can your application's services into the interceptor in case you need to reference anything there also.

Comment: If your angular version allows it, an Http Interceptor adding {withCredentials: true} to every request is definitely the way to go. Worked perfectly for me, using frontend Angular 7.2 and backend Laravel 5.3

Comment: With Flask backend I had to add the following CORS header to the response in order to make it work:
`response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'`

Comment: With .NET Core/.NET 5 backend I had to add `.AllowCredentials()` to the CORS configuration in Startup.cs. The interceptor works in Angular 11 as well. I only had to change the Observable import to `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Thank you @MatterOfFact! It does the trick even though I was setting before:
context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
which I thought was the same. Thanks!