# Setting request cookies angular2 http post request

Tags: angular, cookies, http-post, session-cookies

I have a login service that performs an http request (to a php backend server) and returns a cookie. After login this cookie is needs to be used in all further requests done by the client.

loginservice:

```js
   login(userCredentials:UserCredentials):Observable<any> {    
        this.request.ServiceType = "Connect"
        this.request.SessionId = "sessionlessrequest"
        this.request.Compression = "no"
        this.request.Parameters = userCredentials;
        let jsonRequest = JSON.stringify(this.request)
        return this.http.post("http://localhost/request.php", "data="+ jsonRequest,
            { headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            })
            }).map( (responseData) => {
            this.apiResponse = responseData.json() as ApiResponse
            if (!this.apiResponse.Error) {
                this.sessionData.next(this.apiResponse.Data as UserSessionData)
                this.sessionData.asObservable().share
            } else {
                console.log(this.apiResponse.ErrorMessage)
            }
            return null
        })
```

When doing this call, the cookie response is like this:
[image: getcookie]

I see that I get the session_id from session_start (on my php server)

I when doing the request :

```js
searchExams(searchObject:SearchObject):Observable<any>{
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',)
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true});
        this.request.ServiceType = ServiceType.SearchExams;
        this.request.SessionId = this.userSessionData.SessionId;
        this.request.Compression = "no"
        this.request.Parameters = searchObject;
        let jsonRequest = JSON.stringify(this.request)
        console.log(jsonRequest)
        return this.http.post("http://localhost/request.php", "data="+ jsonRequest, options
            ).map( (responseData) => {
            this.apiResponse = responseData.json() as ApiResponse
            if (!this.apiResponse.Error) {
....
```

I see that the request cookie is totally different from the one I got from the server. Moreover it is always the same PHPSESSID
[image: postrequest]

Do I need to set the request cookie? How?
What am I missing?

Thanks....

Comment: this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602866/how-to-send-cookie-in-request-header-for-all-the-requests-in-angularjs2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this for the login:

```
(...)
return this.http.post("http://localhost/request.php", "data="+ jsonRequest,
    { withCredentials: true,
        headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
    }).map(...)
```

And the other requests:

```
(...)
return this.http.post("http://localhost/request.php", "data="+ jsonRequest,
                      {withCredentials: true}).map(...)
```

Basically, just use `withCredentials` [option](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html) set to `true`.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed the answer.

Comment: Works for me on ionic-angular 3.9.2.  Thanks so much! This question is asked and not answered several other places on the web. I will point those questions to this answer.