# How to use PHP sessions in Angular4 in order to check whether user logged in or not?

Tags: php, angular, session, cookies, angular4-router

I very new to Angular, and i'm working on Angular4 + PHP application, the user credentials are sent to the server from Angular app and it is validated in the PHP server (where db is MySQL). I have created the session variables in PHP, but i don't know how to use them in the Angular app in order to allow or disallow the user from accessing the dashboard, settings, etc. I'm using `Service` and `Guard` in this application,

Angular code:

`home.component.ts`

```
authUser(event){
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uname',event.target[0].value);
    formData.append('pwd',event.target[1].value);
    this.http.post('http://localhost/auth.php', formData)
    .subscribe((data) => {
        let dat = data.json();
        if (dat){
            this.user.setUserBase();   
            this.route.navigate(['report']);
        }
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("Error!", error);
    });
}
```

`user.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class UserbaseService {
    private isLoggedIn;

    constructor() {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }
    setUserBase(){
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
    getUserBase(){
        return (this.isLoggedIn);
    }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'upload',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: UploadComponent
    },
]
```

`auth.guard.ts`

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.user.getUserBase();
}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    require('connect.php');
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM auth WHERE uname='$username' and passwd='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if (!isset($myObj))
         $myObj = new stdClass();

    if ($count == 1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        $myObj->user = $username;
        $myObj->status = "authentic";
    }
    $response = json_encode($myObj);
    echo ($response);
?>
```

These are the navigation I have in my App; `Home` (default page), `Dashboard`, `Settings`, `Logout`.
I want the user to be redirected to `Dashboard` from `Home` if the session is active and if session is not destroyed then user should be redirected to `Home` from `Dashboard`, or `Settings` and also i want to destroy the session by clicking `Logout`. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Using {withCredentials : true} in the HttpClient request worked for me. Add withCredentials to the login request and subsequent page requests. See: [Setting request cookies angular2 http post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286920/setting-request-cookies-angular2-http-post-request)

Answer (score 0):

well [explained](https://github.com/pipiscrew/angular2_small_prjs/tree/master/angular8_with_php_canactivate_%2B_retain_PHPSessionCookie) using Angular8 w/ withCredentials @ HttpHeaders,