# Configure angular project to send http cookie in development mode

Tags: angular

I've written a PHP backend that checks if a request is coming from an authorized user. This is done as simple as using the following code

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["id"])){
    http_response_code(403);
    die("Error. Unauthorized user.");  
}
```

This is perfectly okay in production, but in development I face issues, because angular app running on local development server does not send cookies (nor does the server store it).

How can I configure angular server/app to send session cookies during development? I am using the following code to start an app

```
ng serve --port 4000 --host example.com --ssl true --sslKey path --sslCert path2
```

**UPDATE**

I don't want to change my app logic or anything. this is solley to make development manageable. I need to send cookies at `ng serve` or configure node server to send cookie when it operates. Also if use one version in production, and another in development (as the forcefully implied answer suggests), I need to change it every time push an update and then change it back, leaving me with 2 versions. terrible, terrible practice

**UPDATE 2:**

For additional answer see this Q&A: [sending cookies in Angular app and Access-Control-Allow-Origin in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895152/sending-cookies-in-angular-app-and-access-control-allow-origin-in-development-mo/52895458#52895458)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send "Cookie" in request header for all the requests in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602866/how-to-send-cookie-in-request-header-for-all-the-requests-in-angular2)

Comment: nonono, I don't want to change my app. My app runs just fine in production, in fact, your suggestion will break it. I need to send cookies at `ng serve`. Also if use one verision in production, and another in development, I need to change it every time push an update and then change it back, leaving me with 2 versions. terrible, terrible practice

Comment: Well, I don't know how you expect Angular to send cookies unless you tell it to. To the best of my knowledge, there isn't an option within `ng serve` to make the HttpClient class use the `withCredentials` option.

Comment: You could always add a condition to the Http Interceptor to only pass cookies if your environment is local.

Comment: woa.. crazy, that people have 2 versions for every project that needs authorization. I am pretty sure I will forget to unplug local environemnt in at least one of the next 100 updates :)

Comment: Why do you think you would have two versions of your application if you're simply checking an environment variable provided by Angular itself? You'd be running and deploying the same code locally and in production. The only thing that would be different is the value in your environment.ts / environment.prod.ts. I'm not sure how this is a "terrible, terrible practice"

Comment: Thanks for help. I had to read about environment.ts and how it is used. Although I would prefer sending cookie at ng serve, using evnironment.ts also gets the job done. Post it as an answer if you need points

Comment: You're welcome. I certainly don't need the points, but added an answer for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to pass cookies on every request. `ng serve` doesn't provide a way to turn this feature on, but you could pass cookies conditionally depending on your environment settings:

Here's a sample interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { environment } from '@app/environments/environment.ts'

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept (httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const clonedRequest = httpRequest.clone({
      withCredentials: environment.sendCookies,
    });

    return next.handle(clonedRequest);
  }

}
```

In your environment.ts you can set `sendCookies` to `true` and in environment.prod.ts, set it to `false`. This way you still only have one version of your application, but different behavior where you need it.