# Working with SAP login structure in Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, sap-basis

My web app is Angular 7. I have a API endpoint for the user to login and sending requests to this URL and get the answers.

```
uri = 'https://mybackendurl.com/User';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  signIn(email: string, password: string) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'text/xml',
        ...
      })
    };
    const soapData = '...';

    this.http.post(`${this.uri}`, soapData, httpOptions)
```

The structure I want to build is:

If the user has entered his / her information correctly, will be directed to a panel that uses this infrastructure. However, the user cannot login to the panel even if the user is logged in correctly. Because the URL wants some cookie information -it's called '`mysapsso2`'. (I'm sorry, unfortunately my SAP knowledge is less) And bad news: I can't do it because the post method doesn't generate these unique cookies in Angular. (JS can't or I can't?)

I can't touch the backend URL. In this case, how can I get users to login to this panel using only the frontend skills?

Comment: On the front-end you cannot do HTTP requests to a different domain (in your case, the SAP system), due to a browsers' security feature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: The "sso" in "mysapsso2" probably stands for Single Sign-On. For making calls to it you would have to an OAuth or SAML2 authentication between your back-end and the SAP system.

Comment: @GuilhermeMaeda know and this is not related about my issue. I'm using Chrome CORS extension for temporary solution and it works.

Comment: @GuilhermeMaeda want to ask for a better understanding: Do you think I need a backend server to do that? (Even if we assume that we have solved the CORS problem)

Comment: If you tried using a valid username/password and it didn't accept the request, I assume the server is configured not to accept Basic Authentication, and probably there's a centralized Identity Provider where users have to log in before being redirected to applications.
Here's a doc page from SAP Gateway about web applications accessing SAP systems: https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_gateway20sp12/2.0/en-US/b9/142abe60d448dc932460988573bf4e/content.htm?no_cache=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POST request is done with angular is stateless, so even you have done the login, the cookie is not passed to the backend server.

I think the problem is due to cookie session absence. Try to add it manually with an Angular Interceptor.

For more information read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602866/how-to-send-cookie-in-request-header-for-all-the-requests-in-angular2).