# Session between angular and spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm having problems establishing session between Angular 9 and Spring Boot.

When  call `localhost:8080/test` I always get same `SessionId` from the server.

However, when I call the same endpoint via Angular 9,

```
 this.http.get('localhost:8080/test').subscribe()
```

I get each call different SessionId. Why?

---

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .and()
                    .cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
}
```

TestEndpoint.java

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TestEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void test(){
        log.info(session.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely you're not passing along the cookie holding your SessionID back to the server. XHR requests typically don't add cookies. Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602866/how-to-send-cookie-in-request-header-for-all-the-requests-in-angular2

Comment: Awesome! It works :) Thanks @Simon