# Laravel Sanctum / Angular 2 xsrf-cookie with HttpClient

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-sanctum

Im trying to consume a service in a **Laravel** (Backend) with **Angular 2**. I can doit without any problem if I doit with `axios`, but I need to doit with `HttpClient`

How can I translate this code:

```
const url = `${this.endPoint}/login`;
const urlCsrf = `${this.endPoint}/csrf-cookie`;
const body = { email, password };

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axios.get(urlCsrf).then(() => {
    axios.post(url, body).then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
    });
});
```

to something like this but that it works:

```
//this code dont work returns csrf error
this.http.get(urlCsrf).subscribe(() => {
     this.http.post(url, body).subscribe((resp) => {
         console.log(resp);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using an interceptor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602866/how-to-send-cookie-in-request-header-for-all-the-requests-in-angular2

Comment: What about  `this.http.get(urlCsrf, {withCredentials: true })` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have ran to the same issue recently here is what worked for me:

```js
$data = 'client_id=xxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials';
$url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.x/xx/xxxxx";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  echo curl_error($ch);
  echo "\n<br />";
  $contents = '';
} else {
  curl_close($ch);
}

if (!is_string($contents) || !strlen($contents)) {
echo "Failed to get contents.";
$contents = '';
}
$json = json_encode($contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

That code translates to:

```js
const body = {email, password}
this.http.get(urlCsrf).subscribe(() => {
     this.http.post(url, body, { withCredentials: true }).subscribe((resp) => {
         console.log(resp);
    });
});
```

If you want to write it in a more reactive way:

```js
const body = {email, password}
this.http.get(urlCsrf).pipe(
     switchMap(()=> this.http.post(url, body, { withCredentials: true })
  ).subscribe((resp) => console.log(resp));
```

If you want to apply the `withCredentials` to all requests, you should take a look at the interceptors as mentioned in the comments. A quick example:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CredentialsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      return next.handle(req.clone({ withCredentials: true }));
  }
}
```

and then import it in your `AppModule`

```js
providers: [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: EngagementXSRFInterceptor, multi: true },
]
```

Comment: Ty Eko, please give me a few days to test it.

Comment: Hello with your first option, im receiving error 419, "CSRF token mismatch."

Comment: Could you try in incognito mode or maybe clear your browser cache to make sure they aren't the old cookies?

Comment: In the second option you are calling the subscribe after an rxjs operator, I had to return the respose only with the operators and in my login component call the service method with the subscribe. I receive the same error. CSRF token mismatch.

Comment: I did, i cleared cookies and cache, but only work with axios, I dont know why. Used another browser, and Incognito.

Comment: do you see the csrf token header being added on your http requests?

Comment: I can see it in Postman, dont know how see it in Angular.

Comment: This come in the heder in the route api/csrf-cookie https://i.imgur.com/9ZGSfma.png

Comment: So when you open the inspector in your browser, there is a network tab; there you can see the individual network calls. You can click on them to see what headers they have

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late, but I west a lot of time to find the solution for this issue and I want to share you the final solution that was correct for me.

My setup: Angular 15 - Laravel 10 with sanctum.

Laravel configuration:
.env file: add lines
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

sanctum.php file  add stateful localhost:4200 (for angular ng serve)

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    '%s%s',
    'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,localhost:4200',
    Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
))),
```

cors.php set true for credentials:

```
 'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**RESTART THE SERVER LARAVEL FOR APPLY CHANGES.**

Then, in Angular app:

1. Define interceptor like:

   export class HttpXsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
   headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
   constructor(private tokenService: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {}

intercept(
req: HttpRequest,
next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent> {
req = req.clone({
withCredentials: true,
});

```
req.headers.set('withCredentials', 'true');
if (req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'HEAD') {
  return next.handle(req);
}

const token = this.tokenService.getToken();
// Be careful not to overwrite an existing header of the same name.
if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(this.headerName)) {
  req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(this.headerName, token) });
}

return next.handle(req);
```

}
}

2. In AuthService, put the login method like:

   login(loginForm: LoginForm): Observable {

   return this.http.get('http://localhost/sanctum/csrf-cookie').pipe(
   switchMap(() => {

   ```
    return this.http
      .post<LoginResponse>(base_url + 'access/login', loginForm)
      .pipe(
        tap((data) => {

          const user = new User(
            data.user.id,
            data.user.firstname,
            data.user.lastname,
            data.user.username,
            data.user.email,
            data.user.created_at
          );
          this.user.next(user);
        })
      )
   ```

   }),
   catchError(error => {
   console.error(error);
   return throwError(error);
   })
   );

};

I hope this help someone.