# spring + angular + session cookies

Tags: angular, spring, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am developing an application with a springboot backend and an angular frontend.

Both will be deployed under the same domain. So I will use cookies to maintain the session.

But for development the spring services backend is on `localhost:8080` and the angular app is on `localhost:4200`

I would like to be able to share the cookie on localhost for the different ports. How can I do this?

When I make a call to `localhost:8080/api/service` I can see in the response a `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A2DD58970CB3E8B9DD4F3BF1444D5E55; Path=/api; HttpOnly` But on the next call the cookie is not sent.

I have decided to use cookies instead of sending a token in the header after reading [this guide.](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/)

I don't have any strange configuration, but I understand that it must be due to a security problem. how can I disable this security control for development? What do you do in such cases?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to fix it

From angular side [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35603479/1989579) `this.http.get('http://...', { withCredentials: true })`

From spring side adding cors configuration with `.allowCredentials(true)`