# does xmlhttpRequest's finalurl prevent cookie creation

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

in javascript i use a xmlhttpRequest with finalurl to follow masked url trough multiples crappy redirection and return the true url (and open it directly)

does it prevent middle servers to create their cookies ?
does it make sense ?

i read many things before posting, but this far away from my understanding

Answer (score 0):

[xmlhttprequest and set-cookie & cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977058/xmlhttprequest-and-set-cookie-cookie)

only if you set `xhr.withCredentials = true;`
Please correct me, if I'am wrong

Edit: And if cookies are set by the browser, if doesn't matter. You have only more cookies in your browser, but they should do nothing, because cookies are only datas, that a browser stores in their cookie storage. And a site can only access its own cookies

Comment: if nothing is set, it's false by default ?

Comment: in my test it create half less cookie (!)

Comment: Then add `xhr.withCredentials = false;` under the open method!<br>I've tested the result from withCredentials with `alert(xhr.withCredentials)` The result was false on mozilla firefox for linux